# What is the SQL to get the first val in a column in a table?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce, compact-framework, windows-ce

I want to refactor this code, because it seems wasteful and wacky and weird:

```
public string getVersion()
{
    try
    {
        string dynSQL = "SELECT * FROM invHeader";
        DataSet workSites = dbconn.getDataSet(dynSQL);

        //Go thru dataset and display the working files
        //Only need one, although we'll be duplicating the version
        //per each site as a check value during upgrades
        //return workSites.Tables[0].Rows
        foreach (DataRow row in workSites.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            sVersion = row["ID"].ToString();
            break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Duckbill.ExceptionHandler(ex, "InvHeader.getVersion");
    }

    return sVersion;
} // getVersion
```

I was thinking I could change it to something like this:

```
public string getVersion()
{
    try
    {
        string dynSQL = "SELECT FIRST ID FROM invHeader"; // I also tried "SELECT 1 ID FROM invHeader"
        DataSet workSites = dbconn.getDataSet(dynSQL);
        return workSites.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ID"].ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Platypus.ExceptionHandler(ex, "InvHeader.getVersion");
    }
} // getVersion
```

...but neither query returned what I want (the value of ID in the first row). So what is the SQL to do that.

BTW, I know this *should* be some sort of scalar call, but so many funky Rube Goldbergesque things happen in these homegrown, self-rolled methods that rely on each other, I'm afraid to touch *that*; this little cleanup should be doable without quaking in my booties, though.

### UPDATE

I guess I jumped the gun awarding the answer - "SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM invHeader" in SQL Server CE Query Analyzer results in:

```
FAILED: SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM invHeader 
Error: x800...._E_ERRORSINCOMMAND
Native Error: (25501)
Description: There was an error parsing the query. [Token line number, Token line offset, Token in error,,]
Interface defining error: IID_ICommand
Paaram. 0:1
Param. 1: 8
Param. 2:0
Param. 3: TOP
Param. 4:
Param. 5:
```

This seems cryptic as all get-out, but one thing I do grok is that SQL Server CE Query Analyzer is "not amused."

### UPDATE 2

I found an even more egregious code smell of this ilk; not only does the name of the method lead you to believe it returns a value (well, it does, it's true); but while it's doing that, it gets ALL the records from a potentially large table in order to simply grab the first one (again).

Is it really possible the cat who wrote this didn't get the memo warning against the profligate usage of "SELECT *"?

Can I submit an anonymous entry into the code obfuscation contest?

```
public string getINVSite()
{
    string  siteStr   = "";
    string  dSQL      = "";
    DataSet workSites;

    dSQL      = "SELECT * FROM inventory";
    dbconn    = DBConnection.GetInstance();
    workSites = dbconn.getDataSet( dSQL );

#if true
//            DataRow row = workSites.Tables[0].Rows[0];

    siteStr = "1";
    if (workSites.Tables.Count > 0)
    {
        if(workSites.Tables[0].Rows.Count>0)
            siteStr = workSites.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ID"].ToString();
    }
    return( siteStr );
#else
    //Go thru dataset and display the working files
    foreach( DataRow row in workSites.Tables[0].Rows )
    {
        return( row["ID"].ToString() );
    }

    return( "" );
#endif
} // getINVSite
```

Now you know the burden I bear; if moved with pity, donate to your charity of choice.

### UPDATE 3

Sorry, ctacke; thanks for your help, but this is just too much of a rabbit hole; the original code, although Mad Hatter-worthy, works; I've got stinkier fish to fry, so I'll leave it, at least for now. I tried this:

```
public string getVersion()
{
    string conStr = "Data Source = " + dbconn.filename;
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("conStr in InvHeader.getVersion() is {0}", conStr));//TODO: Remove after testing
    try
    {
        using (SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(conStr))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT ID FROM invHeader", connection))
            using (SqlCeDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    string s = reader.GetString(0);
                    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("version InvHeader.getVersion() is {0}", s));//TODO: Remove after testing
                    return s;// reader.GetString(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    // no result
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Pterodactyl.ExceptionHandler(ex, "InvHeader.getVersion");
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

...and I still get an exception; after seeing the connection string in the first MessageBox.Show(), I don't see the second one.

Comment: Is the ID autoincrement?

Comment: No - they're all the same value, awedly enough.

Comment: I'm stunned. This sounds a bit silly but is your query analyzer connected to the right database? This command should do the job in any SQL db that I know of.

Comment: @JohnBingham: Welcome to my world - when you're dealing with tools and technologies that predate Sabre-Toothed Tigers, you are often stunned. I am connected to the correct database.

Comment: TOP isn't supported in SQL Compact.  Do not use a DataSet - they are abysmal hellspawn.

Comment: @ctacke: I don't disagree with you, but their miasma is scattered throughout this whole project. And it is definitely a house of cards. I am pushing for a complete rewrite, not a refactor. That which is crooked cannot be made straight.

Comment: @ctacke `TOP` is supported as of version 3.5, requires parenthesis.

Comment: yeah, but IIRC, he's using 2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a DataSet.  Ever.

Below is a good first pass.  It could be made faster if the id field is indexed by going TableDirect, but I'd run this first to see if the perf is acceptable.

```
public string GetVersion()
{
    using (var connection = new SqlCeConnection("my connection string"))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var command = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT id FROM invHeader", connection))
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                return reader.GetString(0);
            }
            else
            {
                // no result
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a .NET 1.1 project, which doesn't support implicit var types. What object do I need to replace "var" on this line:
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
?

Comment: I sure like this code better, but replacing the existing method with this one raises an exception (but obfuscates itself, complaining that I need to install some file before it will stop being coy and actually tell me what the problem is). As if I didn't already know better - this is what always happens with this project - any attempt to rehabilitate it just leads to another piece of evidence that it is entirely incorrigible. When it comes to this project, I am definitely in favor of the death penalty (to the project, that is, not the original coders...).

Comment: Any idea *where* it's throwing?  Obviously you have to put in a valid connection string. Or maybe use your existing `dbconn` variable to prevent multiple connections - which might not be supported on an old version of SQL CE.  The reason I prefer this to a scalar or a TOP call is that it can be easily modified to use TableDirect, and if the table you're querying from is on any size, that is about a 10x performance improvement.

Comment: Nevertheless, I'm marking yours as the answer; if we rewrite this, I will avoid Datasets like rancid creamed lima beans.

Comment: >Don't use a DataSet. Ever.

Yeah!

Answer (score 4):

In MS SQL Server CE it's `TOP (N)`:

```
SELECT TOP (1) ID 
FROM invHeader 
ORDER BY ???
```

`ORDER BY` if you don't want an arbitrary record returned.

Comment: It is an arbitrary record - apparently they all have the same val in that column. The existing code just takes the first one, spins like a top for awhile, then exits. Being a quasi-socialist, I'll give the award to the cat with fewer points.

Answer (score 2):

SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM invHeader

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using DataSet, use SqlCommand and ExecuteScalar method.

**Edited**

This code should be equivalent, functional and faster:

```
public string getVersion()
{
    try
    {
        // Use TOP (N) http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb686896.aspx
        string dynSQL = "SELECT TOP (1) ID FROM invHeader";
        return (string)(new SqlCeCommand(dynSQL, dbconn.getConnection()).ExecuteScalar());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Platypus.ExceptionHandler(ex, "InvHeader.getVersion");
    }
} // getVersion
```

Assuming dbconn is a class that could give you a SqlCeConnection calling dbconn.getConnection().

Comment: From my original post: "BTW, I know this should be some sort of scalar call, but so many funky Rube Goldbergesque things happen in these homegrown, self-rolled methods that rely on each other, I'm afraid to touch that; this little cleanup should be doable without quaking in my booties, though."